# ORA-01722: número inválido

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Me ajudem com esse erro por favor, queria entender o porque dele está acontecendo ao tentar recuperar o ID do campo matricula, ao selecionar o campo matricula na minha select list no meu formulário.Segue abaixo o SQL que uso para listar as matriculas

```
SELECT AERONAVE.MATRICULA AS MATRICULA, AERONAVE.ID AS ID FROM AERONAVE AERONAVE
```

Segue o PL/ SQL para preenchimento dessa chave estrangeira ao selecionar o campo matricula que desejo:

```
DECLARE
ID_OCORRENCIA NUMBER;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO OCORRENCIA (CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA, DATA_UTC, UF, MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA)
VALUES (:P2_CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA, :P2_DATA_UTC, :P2_UF, :P2_MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA)
RETURNING ID INTO ID_OCORRENCIA;

INSERT INTO AERONAVE_OCORRENCIA (ID_OCORRENCIA, ID_AERONAVE, OPERACAO)
VALUES (ID_OCORRENCIA, :P2_ID_AERONAVE, :P2_OPERACAO)
```

Quero inserir o valor do ID no campo ID_AERONAVE.

Comment: E qual o valor está sendo passado para a query?

Comment: Quais são os tipos de dados de cada coluna?

Comment: Está sendo passado um varchar2 para a query acima, e queria o retorno do ID correspondente. Para assim inserir ele na tabela OCORRENCIA no campo ID_AERONAVE do tipo number. Acho que isso não está sendo feito corretamente por isso do erro, mas usei isso em outro formulário e funcionou.

Comment: Para sua variável dê um nome diferente do nome do campo da tabela. Pode estar ocorrendo um erromde interpretação.

Comment: Boa prática mesmo em bloco anônimo e nomear variáveis como VS_<NOME> para char , VN_<nome> para numéricos etc

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução prática é você utilizar o seguinte comando após o Insert:

```
SELECT ID
INTO ID_OCORRENCIA
FROM OCORRENCIA 
WHERE CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA = :P2_CLASSIFICACAO_CENIPA
      DATA_UTC = :P2_DATA_UTC,
      UF = :P2_UF,
      MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA = :P2_MUNICIPIO_OCORRENCIA;
```

Outra solução seria utilizar o sub-select abaixo para coletar o novo ID Inserido

No momento do Insert:

```
(SELECT MAX(ID_OCORRENCIA)+1 FROM OCORRENCIA)
```

Ou depois do Insert:

```
(SELECT MAX(ID_OCORRENCIA) FROM OCORRENCIA)
```